Separate `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` in different functions?
I am using cuda to accelarate my code, in which I process every images in a loop. Each image is processed on GPU via cuda.
I refered to cuda-samples to write the code below:

file name: my_cuda.cu

#include "cuda_runtime.h"


int process_one_image(args)
{
    // note that declaration of some params is omitted.
    unsigned char *h_data = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
    unsigned char *h_rgb = (unsigned char *)malloc(size_result);
    // initialize the host memory as an image info.
    ...

    unsigned char *d_data;
    unsigned char *d_rgb;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_rgb, size_result);
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // process the d_data on GPU
    ...

    // copy the result from device to host.
    cudaMemcpy(h_rgb, d_rgb, size_result, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    free(h_rgb);
    free(h_data)
    cudaFree(d_rgb);
    cudaFree(d_data);
}


in the code above, cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy are in the same function process_one_image. and the code is run correctly.
But I want to run this code repeatedly, for like in a loop of more than 10000 times.
So I do not wanna do cudaMalloc and cudaFree every time I process images.
So I wanna change my code into the below arrangement.

cuda_file: my_cuda.cu

#include "cuda_runtime.h"

int initCuda(unsigned char *h_data, unsigned char *h_rgb, unsigned char *d_data, unsigned char *d_rgb)
{
    // note that declaration of some params is omitted.
    unsigned char *h_data = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
    unsigned char *h_rgb = (unsigned char *)malloc(size_result);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_rgb, size);
}

int FinalizeCuda(unsigned char *h_data, unsigned char *h_rgb, unsigned char *d_data, unsigned char *d_rgb)
{
    cudaFree(d_data);
    cudaFree(d_rgb);
    free(h_data);
    free(h_rgb);
}

int process_one_image(unsigned char *h_data, unsigned char *h_rgb, unsigned char *d_data, unsigned char *d_rgb) // note some args are omitted such as size etc.
{

    cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // process the d_data on GPU
    ...

    // copy the result from device to host.
    cudaMemcpy(h_rgb, d_rgb, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}


my_c_code: c_code.c

#include "my_cuda.cu"


int processing_loop(args)  // specific args are omitted
{
    // declaration of host and device memory
    unsigned char *h_data;
    unsigned char *h_rgb;
    unsigned char *d_data;
    unsigned char *d_rgb;

    initCuda(h_data, h_rgb, d_data, d_rgb);
    while (1)
    {
        int ret = process_one_image(h_data, h_rgb, d_data, d_rgb);
    }
    FinalizeCuda(h_data, h_rgb, d_data, d_rgb);

}


Here, you can notice that I wanna cudaMalloc only once in C file, in order to accelarate this code, but I find it did not work correctly. It reported no bugs, but I get nothing from h_rgb.
It seems that(I guess) when processing  cudaMemcpy, It could not find the correct address of d_data and copy to d_data.
So how can I fix this bug, OR, is it a proper way to execute cudaMalloc only once?
The whole code is located in ffio
key_file_path:

ffio/ffio/ffio_c/ffio.c - corresponding to the c_code.c example file.
ffio/ffio/ffio_c/yuv2rgb.cu - corresponding to the my_cuda.cu example.

how to run the whole example:

./compiler.sh to build the executable file main
execute main located in ffio/ffio/ffio_c/test
check the variable ffio->cudaFrame using Ctrl+F


In the second code, you haven't shown where d_rgb and d_data are defined. That missed information is critical to understanding what you have done wrong. Please add a more useful example which shows all the important parts of your code

have added info and how to run the whole example

Basic C/C++: You want the initCuda function to set a pointer in the processing_loop function. So you have to pass a pointer to the pointer to the initCuda function. Here is a minimal fix.
void initCuda(unsigned char **h_data, unsigned char **h_rgb,
             unsigned char **d_data, unsigned char **d_rgb)
{
    *h_data = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
    *h_rgb = (unsigned char *)malloc(size_result);
    cudaMalloc((void **)d_data, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)d_rgb, size);
}
int processing_loop(args)  // specific args are omitted
{
    // declaration of host and device memory
    unsigned char *h_data;
    unsigned char *h_rgb;
    unsigned char *d_data;
    unsigned char *d_rgb;

    initCuda(&h_data, &h_rgb, &d_data, &d_rgb);
    while (1)
    {
        int ret = process_one_image(h_data, h_rgb, d_data, d_rgb);
    }
    FinalizeCuda(h_data, h_rgb, d_data, d_rgb);
}

Note that there are other issues with your code such as your lack of error checking.

thx, it is just a basic C question

thx, it is just a basic C question. But when I add a printf("pointer address: %p\n", (void **)d_data); inside initCuda , and printf("pointer address: %p\n", (void **)&d_data);  outside the initCuda , the address printed on the screen is different. why?

@dongrixinyu Works as expected for me: https://godbolt.org/z/MnGGPh4zG Did you compare two different runs of the same program?

I try to run my code ffio, and the file path is ffio/ffio/ffio_c/yuv2rgb.cu, you can check my printf statements in it. Maybe the difference is caused by other conditions.

@dongrixinyu Do you mean the statements in initCuda compared to the statements in convertYUV2RGBbyCUDA? That second one is in a new function and refers to its own parameter. That would be the pointer to the parameter variable, which is not the same as the variable in the main, to which the initCuda function gets pointed.

yes, thank you for your help. I am still confused. Both initCuda and convertYUV2RGBbyCUDA are called by an FFIO object in ffio/ffio/ffio_c/ffio.c, where you can Ctrl+F to search ffio->cudaFrame->d_yuv_y, this variable are both printf  in initCuda and convertYUV2RGBbyCUDA.  Based on the above, the two printf statements print the address of the same variable. and results show that difference.

@dongrixinyu struct FFIO contains a variable d_yuv_y that is a pointer to unsigned char. When you call initCuda, you pass a pointer to this d_yuv_y variable, a pointer to a pointer. This therefore has an address to that part of the FFIO struct. When you call convertYUV2RGBbyCUDA, you don't pass a pointer to a pointer, just the pointer itself. The parameter is a copy of the original pointer. When you take the address of this variable (&d_yuv_y inside convertYUV2RGBbyCUDA), it is therefore not a pointer to FFIO but instead the address of the local variable.

thx, I finally get your point
